# What are the differences between the three bundled ffmpeg prores encoders?

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, prores

I'm using `ffmpeg` and while looking through the list of codes with `ffmpeg -codecs` I realized there are actually three different prores encoders:

- prores
- prores_aw
- prores_ks

What are the differences between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the following explanation on the [ffmpeg wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VFX):

> Fmpeg comes with 3 different prores encodes: "prores", "prores_ks"
>   (formerly named "prores_kostya") and "prores_aw" (formerly named
>   "prores_anatolyi"). In our testing we've used the "prores" and the
>   "prores_ks" encoders and found "prores_ks" to be the best encoder to
>   use. It is the only one that supports the 4444 colorspace and although
>   it may be slightly slower. The color quality of the videos produced by
>   these two codecs was visually indistinguishable Because of the 4444
>   support we've decided to go with Kostya's version of prores.

So, if you want to do 4444 and need alpha channel support, `prores_ks` is the way to go.

[This blog post](https://wideopenbokeh.com/AthenasFall/?p=111) also suggests that `prores_ks` has a smaller footprint, and that `prores` and `prores_aw` are basically the same.

Comment: [Beware](http://video.stackexchange.com/q/20024/1871) of 4444+alpha encoding.

Comment: @Gyan Heads up for new people, the 4444+alpha bug has been fixed. Just make sure you're running the latest FFmpeg build.